# how to define hardware and network requirement for future software system

Tags: hardware

my team is starting to work on creating functional and technical requirements for big software. As a part of this assignment we are asked to provide well grounded hardware requirements. 
I have no idea where to start and how to do it, have you ever seen methodology or any practice that can provide such requirements? how should we decide and state that we need this or that processor? actually the system will work on any modern hardware. please tell me about your experience

Comment: Server based? Stand-alone? Compiled code? Virtual Machine? Memory Used? CPU Load? Muti-threaded? Muti-Process? Database? Application Server? *NIX Based? Windows Based?  I don't think you;ll get much of an answer here unless you show benchmarks and your development platform...... Cheers .... Also it might be time to execute load times, execution times etc....

Comment: Besides being a duplicate, there are absolutely not enough details to even *begin* to answer.

Comment: Ask. The. Vendor.

Comment: Ehdrian, no matter its server side or not or whats the application server I am asking about methodolgy that will guide me through the process of creating hardware requirements. And how should I know CPU or memory load of system that is supposed to be created in years???

Answer (score -2):

"big software" is way too broad to explore the hardware options you might have. 
From the top of my head, you'll have to define:

- the RAM GB / SMT core ratio [e.g. I go for 2 / 1 ]
- IOPS
- HDD / SSD [ HDD for capacity, or SSDs for high IOPS  ]
- client side networking [ 10GbE, 1GbE, low latency ... ]
- switches [ # ports, # uplinks]
- blocking factor

Then, based on your internal workflow, plan hardware [or VMs if suitable] for:

- sandbox system(s)  [ QA and DEV ]
- versioning control
- backup
- redundancy [ how much money your company loses if "big software" is down ]

Again, your question is too broad, try discussing the above inside your group then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: could you please explain the reason behind the downvotes ?

Comment: Well lets concentrate on CPU, I will have functional requirements in 6 months and i want to know based on what I should be able to say that we need this or that CPU?

Comment: @AndreiGrb discuss with the vendor of the software for recommendations on the hardware configuration. As you mentioned "big software", he must have some profiling information. Let's say Oracle or SAP - based on the modules that you'll implement, the number of users that will use the application and the recommendations from the vendor, you should have the start data for the capacity planning.

Comment: there is a team of developers who has to develop this product for the Government. They say it can work on anything that has windows. The number of users is around 1000. The problem is if we will say lets say we need this or that configuration and later somebody will ground that we had to buy other configuration then whole team will actually go in prison

Comment: @AndreiGrb - **"it can work on anything that has windows"** have that signed in writing. Install the application on a Windows phone. Sue them. Make lots of money, get a yacht, live your life. Seriously, you can't accept that as specifications - if they know their product, they have to provide specifications for it.